# After moving Wordpress to a different domain some pages not working correctly

Tags: wordpress

I just moved my whole website with database to new server ( with Duplicator plugin ). And now all pages working fine except Homepage, FAQ and Gallery (no footer, no content). You can see here : [Website](http://baivaras.com/sandra)

Any code was not changed before and after moving. Database imported correctly I think(links changed as well).

How should I fix it?

Thank you in advance guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your permalinks will need refreshing and make sure the URL is correct under settings -> general.

- Step 1: In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".
- Step 2: Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".
- Step 3: Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.

Comment: I did that, nothing changed. I deleted .htaccess file and saved permalinks aswell :(

Comment: Try changing the permalink structure to "Plain" and test the pages that aren't working currently, if they work then you know the problems to do with permalinks :)

Comment: Ok, if my pages 7 and 20 not working. I did flush manualy with this code: `add_action('init',function(){

 //rewrite
 add_rewrite_rule('sandra','index.php?&p=20','top');

 //flush
 flush_rewrite_rules();

});` And its still not working. Can you explain deeply for me? I'm not very good at wordpress

Comment: Do you want me to take a quick look on teamviewer for you and sort it?

Comment: Yes, sure. But first, I'm using front-page.php for static homepage and using `wp_query` with `page_id` array, then I delete my page id its working without content. How should we contact for TW details? I'll contact you tomorrow evening, now I need to go :(

Comment: Add me on Skype tomorrow: Jamie17x (I will be on around 10.30PM GMT) and I will take a look on TW, could be a few things causing it

Comment: Already found the problem.. Gallery plugin was stucked and the same gallery was on these 3 pages. Thank you for your help anyway ! @jamie